# How Isolate y from $a=\sqrt{(y^2+(a+x)^2)^3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, substitution

Just that!
I'm asking for a method to isolate $y$ from such expressions:

$$a=\sqrt{(y^2+(a+x)^2)^3}$$

or even easier:

$$a=\sqrt{(y^2+x^2)^3}.$$

EDIT:

I'm just trying to revisit some of the basics in algebraic equation manipulation. 
Even it's sooo easy to find the school examples with squares or cubes, dealing with radicals can twist into strange paths.
The above expression ($a=\sqrt{(y^2+x^2)^3}$) can turn into a monster just as you add another simple term:

$$a=\sqrt{(y^2+x^2)^3} + \sqrt{(y^2-x^2)^3}$$

I can not see now how squaring the two sides could help in y isolation...

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe squaring both sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to see how $\sqrt{(y^2+(a+x)^2)^3}$ is built starting from y

$\begin{align} 
 & y \\ 
 & {{()}^{2}}\to {{y}^{2}} \\ 
 & +{{(a+x)}^{2}}\to {{y}^{2}}+{{(a+x)}^{2}} \\ 
 & {{()}^{3}}\to {{({{y}^{2}}+{{(a+x)}^{2}})}^{3}} \\ 
 & \sqrt{{}}\to \sqrt{{{({{y}^{2}}+{{(a+x)}^{2}})}^{3}}} \\ 
 & =a \\ 
\end{align}$

So starting from y you do the sequence of operations $$()^2 \to +{{(a+x)}^{2}}\to ()^3 \to  \sqrt{{}}$$ to produce a. You can recover y by starting from a and undoing those operations in reverse order $$()^2 \to ()^{\frac{1}{3}} \to -{{(a+x)}^{2}} \to \sqrt{{}}$$ to give

$\begin{align} 
 & a \\ 
 & ()^2 \to a^{2} \\ 
 & ()^{\frac{1}{3}}\to a^{\frac{2}{3}} \\ 
 & -(a+x)^2\to a^{\frac{2}{3}}-{(a+x)}^{2} \\   
 & \sqrt{}\to \pm \sqrt{a^{\frac{2}{3}}-(a+x)^{2}} \\ 
 & = y \\ 
\end{align}$

Parsing the original expression this way can help you to see how to unravel it.

Comment: I will need a little more time than I spend reading to clearly understand your explanation (my fault), but I am really grateful for you generosity and your time writing this. And I'm sure it will help any other else.

Comment: This method won't help much in your edit as now y appears twice in your equation and you cannot parse the right hand side expression "starting from y".

Comment: I know, but as for the original question I'd like to mark your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the square of both sides of $a=\sqrt{(y^2+(a+x)^2)^3}$, one may get
$$ a^2=(y^2+(a+x)^2)^3$$
Now we apply the cube root,
$$ a^\frac{2}{3}=y^2+(a+x)^2$$
Then, we have
$$ y^2=a^\frac{2}{3}-(a+x)^2$$
Finally, we take the square root of both sides,
$$y=\pm \sqrt{a^\frac{2}{3}-(a+x)^2} $$

Comment: Really been an stupid not seeing it as I wrote it, but as it's a part of a more complex expression (again I'm sorry for not including it from the start), I can not see if squaring both sides would be an answer. If I'm not wrong again, my edit should show how it gets harder just adding a simple additional term.

Comment: You will have to square your second expression twice. The first square will create several terms and one with a single square root. Re-arrange then square again to remove the root. you end up with a nasty polynomial in y.