# How isolate y from $a=\sqrt{(y^2+x^2)^3} + \sqrt{(y^2-x^2)^3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, substitution

$$a=\sqrt{(y^2+x^2)^3} + \sqrt{(y^2-x^2)^3}$$

I need to isolate y in a family of such expressions.
Can someone give me a guide to learn how deal with those...
There's no further information or context. I've found a lot of information to work with powers but it's not easy to find information about radicals.
Maybe there's some kind of algorithm or method to go ahead with these expressions, but I've been unable to find any.

Comment: Thanks for your edit Parcly!

Comment: Can you square both sides, simplify by moving  resulting single radical to one side and square again?

Comment: I always thought that square a sum leaves a term at original power and, in this case, at the "a" side the root will remain. I'll give it a try!!

Comment: See the result (ugly) using this by [*Wolfram Alpha*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+a+%3D+sqrt((y%5E2+%2B+x%5E2)%5E3)%2Bsqrt((y%5E2+-+x%5E2)%5E3),+for+y)

Comment: Didn't knew the tool! A valuable one, as your comment. But I still would like a guide to the method to generate this solution...

Comment: Try it with this simpler variant because the steps are identical [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+a+%3D+sqrt((y%2Bx))%2Bsqrt((y-x)),+for+y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some answers from [yesterday's post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980246/how-isolate-y-from-a-sqrty2ax23), the main takeaway is not to be afraid of the gangliness of the expression. Additional tips to help:

- Square the right hand side, using the rule, $(x+y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2$
- Treat square roots as half-powers: $\sqrt{x} = x^{1/2}$
- Remember that products of powers with the same exponent combine their bases through multiplication, powers of same bases add, and powers-of-powers multiply: $$x^j\cdot y^j = (xy)^j \\ x^j\cdot x^k = x^{j+k} \\ (x^j)^k = x^{jk}$$

Try with these rules, first.  There is value in working these things out by hand.  Later, you can find online solvers that will help verify the answer.

Comment: Even the answer is itself a luxury, your advice: "There is value in working these things out by hand" is one of the best things it ever happened to me at stackexchenge... ;)